# Question about Request and Session with CXF, JAX-RS webservice

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf, jax-rs

I have a webservice set up using CXF, JAX-RS and Spring. I have the following method:

```
@GET
@Path("/getPayload")
@Produces("application/XML")
public Response makePayload(){
    Payload payload = new Payload();
    payload.setUsersOnline(new Long(200));

    return Response.ok().entity(payload).build();
}
```

How can I get access to the `HttpRequest` object in my `makePayload()`?

Will a call to this method generate a Session, and if so, can I get a handle to it and  will that session be persistent for all subsequent requests from the same client?

Comment: John,
note that you should not put an action into your URLs. Why it does not harm anything (since URIs are to be opaque) it makes it look like you are thinking 'in the wrong terms'.

Instead of sth like

GET /stockquotes/APPL/getPayload

it should be 

GET /stockquotes/APPL

because GET already means 'get payload'.

Jan

Answer (score 3):

[`@Context`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) can be used to obtain contextual Java types related to the request or response:

```
@GET
@Path("/getPayload")
@Produces("application/XML")
public Response makePayload(@Context Request request) {
    //...
}
```